# out of spool space error - help to optimize sql/primary index

Tags: sql, teradata

I am using the following TeraData code:

```
CREATE SET TABLE WebSesData1
(
    Id CHAR(5) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC
    ,WebSessionId BIGINT
) PRIMARY INDEX (WebSessionId);

CREATE SET TABLE WebSesData1
(
    Id CHAR(5) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC
    ,WebSessionId BIGINT
) PRIMARY INDEX (WebSessionId);

SELECT 
    One.Id AS PickedId
    ,Two.Id AS InteractingId 
    ,COUNT(*) AS Evidence
FROM WebSesData1 AS One
INNER JOIN WebSesData2 AS Two
ON
    One.Id  < Two.Id
    AND One.WebSessionId = Two.WebSessionId
GROUP BY 1,2
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY One.Id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) <= 10
;
```

to identify for each Id in WebSesData1 the TOP 10 different Ids in WebSesData2, which share the same WebSessionId. Occasionally, I still get out of spool space error for the above query. I already write data in 'chunks' into WebSesData1 and WebSesData2 in an attempt to make this more efficient.

Is there anything I can do to make the above more efficient? Either by changing the SQL and/or primary index. I can also create different working tables. Any suggestions very much welcome.

Comment: How many rows per `WebSessionId` exist in average/max? And how many rows are in both table?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help. I don't see the full relationship between the description of what you want and the query.

Comment: @dnoeth - there are websession ids with 6000-ish rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you please clarify what you do not understand. IMHO this is quite a simple problem and the working tables should capture this very well.

Comment: This is probably the best you can get, join on the PI, but when you join two IDs with **n** rows each you create an intermediate result of **n*(n-1)/2 rows**, for n=6000 it's almost 18,000,000 rows before aggregation. And this spool might be skewed, too.

Comment: @dnoeth - sorry are you saying that my code is the best I can get? If not please post answer. Thanks.

Comment: Your code is fine :-)

Comment: @csetzkorn . . . It is a simple problem for *you* because you understand the domain.  I can't figure out what `One.Id  < Two.Id` has to do with the question you are asking.

Comment: Ids have to be different - for a One.Id I want to know all Two.Ids which were part of the same session. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: dnoeth's explanation is spot on. Beyond that, if you could provide the EXPLAIN output it would help confirm what dnoeth mentioned.